# Where is the bounty icon?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, bounty

Just received an email (4 hours ago) saying

> Your bounty on the question … [iPhone: How to ensure iBook files are stored locally](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/331227/iphone-how-to-ensure-ibook-files-are-stored-locally) … ended and will be auto-closed after the 24-hour grace period expires.
>   Please review the answers.
>   If you feel one of them deserves your bounty, **award it by clicking the bounty icon to the left of the answer**.

It's not 24 hours yet... but I cannot see the bounty-reward icon.

I must miss something... please let me know what!

-- edit --

Cannot see the alarm clock ... please see the screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bounty grace period for that question started on Jan 14 at 8:17, which was exactly 7 days after it started. You were emailed about the grace period being active on Jan 15 at 0:00 (which is the scheduled task that looks for bounties in grace period mode and emails all users about it). The bounty was formally removed due to an expired grace period on Jan 15 at 10:02 and could no longer be awarded at that time.

I've no idea why you would've gotten an email that was sent over two days ago just today. It's possible you just didn't notice it until now, or your email client was holding it up somewhere. But the system functioned as intended here and there's nothing to fix.

Unfortunately, we're not able to manually alter the state of bounties and this question will just have to go without a bounty award.

Comment: Just looked again at the email, Google says it was sent "16 hours ago"... So maybe the email was stuck in a queue somewhere (or Google had a problem). Thanks for the investigation anyway, that's good to know the system is working fine!

Answer (score 2):

On a practical matter, moderators can't intervene in this so if you felt this was a bug and you wanted a developer to review / manually award the bounty - please use the contact us link and refer to this post.

If it's just about making sure you were looking in the right place, here is where would expect to see the button on Safari without any content blockers engaged: below the voting triangles and the green check mark.

[image]

Don't worry about the clock icon - that is NOT the bounty award, and it's relating to moderator tools to see the history on the post. The bounty award is large and colorful (dark blue like the offer bounty button in my experience)

It should be next to “if you...” since there are anither 5 hours left in the grace period. (4h57m and counting down)

You can only award it to the single answer. [image]

Comment: Made an edit that shows the "bounty clock" does not appear ; note that at the time the edit was made, the bounty grace period did not expire.

Comment: You are correct @RingØ - if you wanted to ping the developers - see the edit above and the [contact link below](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/contact). They might be able to help you award the bounty if that's the reason why you asked here.

Comment: Just fyi, the "bounty ended" event in the timeline is *after* the grace period. Those events are not created until the grace period was over and the bounty was formally removed from the question. It was over 2 days ago and cannot be awarded.

Answer (score 1):

**There were no eligible answers for the bounty to be awarded, *but the email was also too late.***

According to the [timeline](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/331227/timeline):

1. The first (accepted) answer was posted on Jan 5
2. The bounty was posted on Jan 7 with the reason "Draw attention"
3. The bounty ended on Jan 15 with no additional answers
4. (from OP) The email reminder was received on Jan 17 after the bounty has ended

Putting a bounty implies that either the question is not yet answered, or existing answers are not satisfying. Thus, old answers cannot be awarded a bounty that is put after that. The only exception is "Reward existing answer" which can be awarded to any answers on the question.

As per FAQ on Meta SE, [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065):

> #### Can I award a bounty to an old answer?
>
> Yes, you can award your bounty to any answer on the question. This makes it possible for users to reward particularly good answers with more rep than a standard upvote would provide.
>
> To indicate that your bounty will be awarded to an existing answer, choose "Reward existing answer" when asked "Why are you starting this bounty?"
>
> > [image: Reward existing answer]

---

**That said...**

[Stack Exchange will send bounty reminder emails even though there are no eligible answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285799/241919). Also, since you received the email on Jan 17, perhaps [you received the email too late](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/377005)?